# Where to keep and how to propagate in memory data in iOS project using VIPER pattern?

Tags: ios, viper-architecture

I have a flow in my project where I have different screens to edit different parts of an entity, that is created only in the end of this flow. How do I organize the code in VIPER in this scenario?

Example:

I want to create a Test entity. It has a Title and Description, questions and some auxiliar text at the end. Each part is edited on a separate screen, in sequence, like:

Create Title/Description ---> Create Questions ---> Enter Auxiliar Text ---> Create

Where do I keep all the data needed at the end?
Do I pass it for each presenter? Do I keep all of them in the Interactor?

Answer (score 0):

In our team we decided that `Presenter` can store some state. So we pass model to the next module and store it in `Presenter`.

You can find demo usage of **VIPER** architecture in my open source project [here](https://github.com/ismetanin/ViperDemo), but there is no example for flow that you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

As explained lucidly & succinctly in https://theswiftdev.com/the-ultimate-viper-architecture-tutorial the *interactor* zone quarantines how the acquisition of entities/data are technologically obtained.  For example, your in-memory data might be simple DRAM right now, but conceivably could be in the future or on a different platform be cache-coherent NUMA for many-core procressor or TimesTen in-memory database engine or shared memory interprocess.  The value of the VIPER architecture is that over time the details of which variant of in-memory {UMA DRAM, ccNUMA, TimesTen, shared memory} is quarantined in *interactor* zone so that upheavals due to these differing technologies of representing in-memory data does not commingle & intertwine with business logic over in the *presenter* zone (or worse, throughout other zones too).  Plus, as your app goes from its first platform to 2nd & subsequent platforms, you will appreciate the ability to swap in at build-time different interactor zones for simple UMA DRAM on one small platform, ccNUMA on a many-core platform, TimesTen on a data-center scale, and shared-memory on, say, an embedded system or general-purpose desktop OS.